# Using a nema 6-20 outlet with a typical 5-15 device

Tags: electrical, wiring, air-conditioning

I have a nema 6-20 outlet that worked with a window air conditioning unit that I recently replaced. The replacement unit has a typical nema 5-15 plug. The new unit pulls 11.5A and uses 110V. With only a simple converter ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B075FTC9RT/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075FTC9RT)) like the one linked, can I safely use this unit? I believe that I can but I just want to check to see if I need a transformer for a voltage step down of some kind.

Comment: "This is a plug adapter and NOT a voltage converter" right in the listing.  *and* it doesn't have a UL listing (because UL doesn't list thing that are specifically designed to defeat the keying of receptacles)  *and* it's on Amazon which is now worse than eBay thanks to all the third party sellers.

Comment: Good chance of turning your AC unit to a heating unit(fire).  Instead of trying to fool around making it work, add a simple 120 volt circuit to room, or changing the AC unit.

Comment: So you wired 240v to a 120v receptacle? Bad form and a code violation I tried loading the device but at this point I would ask how you did this. A black and white on 6-20 is 240v , putting those same black and white on a 5-15 is a fire in the making of just letting the magic smoke out., I finally got that page to load , yikes that is just an adapter. Turn that breaker off now!!! And it looks like others say the same!

Comment: A review of the device on Amazon: "THIS KILLED MY AC UNIT INSTANTLY. SO MAD
Reviewed in the United States on July 2, 2020
I bought this adapter for the outlet next to my ac unit. I have had an extension cord leading from my ac unit to a different wall outlet, because the outlet directly below had those parallel prongs. So I bought this adapter, plugged it into the wall, and then plugged in my ac unit, and it immediately killed my ac. I tried to restart it and tried the extension cord again and nothing. I’m so furious right now I could explode! DONT BUY THIS ADAPTER! Not worth the chance!!"

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not! What you linked simply allows you to plug your 120 volt device into a 240 volt outlet. Unless the device has universal voltage input (which I highly doubt your AC has), this is just about guaranteed to destroy it.

By the way, a transformer rated for 12 amps will be expensive and heavy. You’d be much better off returning the AC and getting a 240 volt unit.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing sold on Amazon will do what you want, *even if* you ignored all the cheap Chinese crud that isn't even safe.  (well okay, I'm sure they sell some Schneider or Siemens 1.5 KVA isolation transformers at nosebleed prices, but it would be cheaper just to go back to the store and get a 230V air conditioner).

The "path of least resistance" (heh) for this project is to have an electrician or other qualified person come in, rewire the circuit breaker panel to make this circuit 120V (which is super easy for them), and change the socket to a NEMA 5-15 or 5-20 type.

This will involve basically not using half of the breaker, but who cares?

While they're at it, they can change it to a *duplex* (2-socket) NEMA 5-15 or 5-20... so they can grab literally any receptacle, and don't need to search for a pricey 1-socket NEMA 5-20.  There's no requirement to have it be 1 socket only. (it even could've even been a duplex NEMA 6-20; they make those).

Answer (score 2):

NO there is NOTHING safe about this!
Do not leave that 120v receptacle wired to the 240v that was there this is dangerous!

The plug adapter is just that it will not change anything but connect to the receptacle, anything else plugged in will quickly go up in smoke and may shock you also.